# How to populate a menu using "path_menu"?

Tags: python

There is an option in `class bpy.types.Menu(bpy_struct)` called `path_menu` which says it can be used to "Populate a menu from a list of paths."

I'd like to use this to populate a menu from a folder of text files. I can't find any examples of how to do this though. Could someone point me to a menu example that uses `path_menu` or demonstrate how I can use this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Seems there's a pretty straight forward example in space_text.py

```
class TEXT_MT_templates_py(Menu):
    bl_label = "Python"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.path_menu(
            bpy.utils.script_paths("templates_py"),
            "text.open",
            props_default={"internal": True},
        )
```

path_menu can be used within the main draw function. Would be great if I could figure out how to make the contents of self.path_menu a sub menu item (rather then enumerating out directly into the menu).

EDIT: Just to be clear, I mean "would be great if I could" create a sub menu from the path_menu contents directly within the original menu itself (without having to create a whole separate, other class menu to call on).

Comment: Is this an answer to your question?

Comment: Hi. Yeah. Sorry, it's telling me I can't accept my own answer for  two days (otherwise I would have marked it answered). I would like to figure out if it were possible to collapse the contents of path_menu into a sub menu, but not sure that warrants creating a another entry.